# accept option for Drag and Drop using jQuery

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

```
$(".ssource").droppable({
        addClasses: false,
        greedy: true,
        accept:function(ele){
            if($(this).hasClass("Dropped") != true){
                 return true;
            }
            }else{
                 return false;
            }
        },
        drop: function(event, ui) {
                 $(this).addClass("Dropped");
                },
});
```

accept option of droppable is call on click of the Draggable element but i want to check draggable is valid or not when it hover on Droppable area.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Over and Out to valid the Droppable area.

```
$(".ssource").droppable({
        greedy: true,
        //Active the Drop Area
        over: function(event, ui) {
           $(this).addClass("validArea");
        },
        //Deactive the Drop Area if the item drop.
        drop: function(event, ui) {
           $(this).removeClass("validArea");
        },
        //Deactive the Drop Area if item outside the area.
        out: function(event, ui) {
           $(this).removeClass("validArea");
        }
});
```

ValidArea is your new class to make the Droppable area look valid as the image is hover on the area.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, there is an example with draggable linked to droppable. In the droppable element, use the same "accept" option

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  accept: ".ssource",
```

Comment: Thanks for replaying,by default behavior "accept" may have selecter or function will call when we select/click any draggable element. But i want it will call when draggable will "hover" to the Droppable Area or element.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your test. Why you want to test if the dragged element is or not valid. Either it is valid ! or you can tell your droppable area to don't accept it.

Comment: Ok. I am trying explain to understand batter.  My purpose is to display error related to draggable which i pick to drop into drop area. if i write function in accept(which i done in question) this will call for each droppable when i click on that draggable element. and i have multiple droppable area. So i want to do that when draggable element start the dragging and hover to the droppable area that time error(i am appending HTML msg to top center of body)would be show.

Comment: I'm not sure I have clearly understood, but there are two differents 'accpet' one for draggable elements, the other for droppable elements. Anyway, I don't understand " i want to do that when draggable element start the dragging and hover to the droppable". Drag start and droppable hover are two distinct events. You want to achieve something on drag start or on droppable hover ?? Chose your side.

Comment: TCHdvlp@ Thanks for replaying. First,Draggable have not 'accept' in option.I want on droppable hover. i tried 'over' of droppable but only first time it will execute at hover for each draggable element. when first time hover done, 'accept' function start execute on click of draggable.